# Perguntas com títulos iguais mas com contexto e problemas diferentes

Tags: debate, perguntas, título

Respondi essas duas perguntas:

- [Como pego a data do Calendário no Android?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/231283/como-pego-a-data-do-calend%C3%A1rio-no-android/231288#231288)
- [Como pegar data do calendário em android?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/231242/como-pegar-data-do-calend%C3%A1rio-em-android/231262#231262)

Basicamente estão com mesmo título mas o contexto e o problema são diferentes. Talvez o autor não estava muito feliz na elaboração do título. Eu apenas respondi sem questionar. Acho que não tem muito o que fazer né?! Ou tem?

Comment: Tem, editar o titulo. Ainda mais se você entendeu a diferença entre elas.

Comment: @Articuno acredite, eu nem tinha lido o titulo direito. Só depois que estava olhando meu histórico que percebi que tinha duas perguntas com títulos iguais. heuhueh

Comment: Provavelmente de ambas, o título não é trágico, mas pode ser melhor.

Answer (score 4):

Ao meu ver o erro *era de sintaxe*, no caso creio que títulos que descrevem a mensagem de erro sempre são mais úteis, ainda mais para futuros visitantes que vierem por buscadores, sendo do site ou de outros buscadores, como Google por exemplo.

Então tomei a liberdade de mudar o título da pergunta para:

> Erro "Expression expected"

Edição: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/231242/revisions

Comment: Faz todo sentido. Eu deveria ter editado, como o @articuno disse nos comentários, porém fui perceber bem depois que os títulos estavam iguais. Ai quando fiz a pergunta aqui, queria deixar para ver qual seria a opinião de vocês quanto a isso.

Comment: @white não sei se você nota minhas atividades de edição no site, mas o que mais ajusto são titulos, então essa é minha opinião hehehe, se o problema é uma "mensagem de erro" geralmente os usuários vão procurar perguntas com a tal mensagem, então nada melhor para o site e para o google/outros que o usuário consiga encontrar assim :D